# I want to concatenate two embeddings using keras embeddings layers and train the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have data consisting of two-column (titles, label) for binary classification(0,1) I have generated two embeddings (raw text by SBERT and Knowledge graphs embeddings) of sizes (14196,384) and (6063,384) respectively. And now I want to concatenate these two embeddings to train the model by Keras embeddings layer. I am trying to embed my generated embeddings as pre-trained weights in the embeddings layers of Keras. I am using the following code.

```
num_epochs = 20
batch_size = 64
train_text, temp_text, train_labels, temp_labels = train_test_split(df['Title'], df['Label']
                                                                    random_state=2022, 
                                                                    test_size=0.3, 
                                                                    stratify=df['Label'])
train_data=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_text, train_labels))
valid_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((temp_text, temp_labels))

ip1 = tf.keras.layers.Input((14169,)) # number of input sentences 
ip2 = tf.keras.layers.Input((6063,))  

text_embed = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(14169, 384, input_length=14169,weights=[r_text],trainable=False)(ip1) #text embeddings(14196,384)
KG_embed = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(6063, 384, input_length=14169,weights=[embeddings_rdf_train],trainable=False)(ip2) #knowledge graphs embeddings (6063,384)

normal_kg = tf.keras.layers.Dense(14196)(ip2) #trying to match embeddings dimensions
normal_kg = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((14196,1))(normal_kg)
embedding_KG = KG_embed(normal_kg)

concat = layerlist = [text_embed, embedding_KG]
concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis = -1)(layerlist)

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation = 'relu',name='dense_1')(concat)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(outputs)

model = tf.keras.models.Model([ip1, ip2], outputs)
model.summary()
```

```
getting error:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-4409dc2687a5> in <module>()
      7 normal_kg = tf.keras.layers.Dense(14196)(ip2)
      8 normal_kg = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((14196,1))(normal_kg)
----> 9 embedding_KG = KG_embed(normal_kg)
     10 
     11 concat = layerlist = [text_embed, embedding_KG]

TypeError: 'KerasTensor' object is not callable
could you please tell. How I should do according to my problem or whether I am going right?
```

I have less idea about keras. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to convert your text into the indices necessary for each of the embeddings? Without this, your model will never work. And only you have these mappings since you trained the embeddings.

Aside from that, answering the question: you cannot use a `Sequential` model with two inputs.

Build a two input model

```
#question: do your titles really have 14169 words each? Sounds very weird
ip1 = tf.keras.layers.Input((14169))
ip2 = tf.keras.layers.Input((14169))

text_embed = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(14169, 384, input_length=14169,weights=[r_text],trainable=False)(ip1)
KG_embed = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(6063, 384, input_length=6063,weights=[embeddings_rdf_train],trainable=False)(ip2)

concat = layerlist = [text_embed, KG_embed]
concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis = -1)(layerlist)

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation = 'relu',name='dense_1')(concat)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(outputs)

model = tf.keras.models.Model([inp1, inp2], outputs)
model.compile(...)
model.fit(...)
```

Comment: First of all, I want to concatenate two embeddings that are coming from text data (titles) and knowledge graphs (created for the same title data).  Because the inputs are not different. So is it required to create two layers?

Comment: I did not understand by - "Do you know how to convert your text into the indices necessary for each of the embeddings? Without this, your model will never work. And only you have these mappings since you trained the embeddings" Could you please tell? Dataset have titles of different word sizes (10, 18...max size =456). The train_data.shape=14169. So the embeddings of dimensions (14169,384) and another knowledge graph embeddings dimension (6063,384). So I provided input of this size.